# How could register app from S3 bucket without public permission in Spring data flow server

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I have running data flow server in PCF. And i want to register app(http://....jar) which is from S3 bucket and it does not have public access.

I see there are only 3 params available(--name, --type, --uri) for app register, how could pass credentials like --aws.accessKeyId and --aws.secretKey.

Comment: Please share your approach

Comment: I am trying to register app in SCDF by, "app register --name processor-service --type processor 
  --uri https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/....jar"

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, we do not have a AWS-native approach to resolve Spring Cloud Stream or Spring Cloud Task applications from S3 buckets directly. We have an [open story](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer/issues/82) on this matter, however. Today, you can only resolve publicly accessible application artifacts from S3 buckets.

Alternatively, you could host and resolve the applications using the [SCDF App Tool](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/scdf-app-tool) that we ship.

There are few other [alternatives](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-cloudfoundry-app-resolution-options), too, so feel free to try out the options and choose the method that works best for your use-case.